# Atmega32 shifting PORTA won't cycle through entire register

Tags: bit-shift, atmel

I am trying to create a program to flash an LED on each bit of a development board for PORTA using a shift.  When I simulate the program, instead of a shift between bit 0-7, the output is 0x01, 0x02, ox04, 0x10.  Then it starts over.  Is there some reason I can't shift through that 8-bit register completely?  Any help would be appreciated.

```
#define F_CPU 1000000UL
#include <avr/io.h>
#include <util/delay.h>


int main(void)
{
    DDRA = 0xFF;

    while (1)
    {
       PORTA = 0x01;
       _delay_ms(1000);
       for (int count = 0; count < 7; count++)
            {
            PORTA = 1<<PORTA;
            _delay_ms(1000);
            }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you mean this:

```
for (int count = 0; count < 8; count++)
{
    PORTA = 1<<count;
    _delay_ms(1000);
}
```